# How to pass values to a list in ActiveCampaign using C#

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I have a list in ActiveCampaign (Email Marketing API). In there I need to add contacts who have three parameters `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`. Those parameters should be passed to that list using C# console app.
So first I need to access to the ActiveCampaign API using its API Key. And there is also a list ID for that particular list. Then I need to pass values to that list using my C# console app.
Here is my sample code.
Please help me to achieve it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ActiveCampaignListAdd
{
class Program
{

    private const string URL = "https://osandadeshannimalarathna.api-us1.com";
    private string API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private static string api_action = "/admin/api.php?api_action=contact_add";
    private static string listIDAndStatus = "?listid=2&status=1";
    //  private string api_output = "Json";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(api_action + listIDAndStatus).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body. Blocking!
            var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Contacts>>().Result;
            foreach (var d in dataObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d.firstName);
                Console.WriteLine(d.lastName);
                Console.WriteLine(d.email);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
    

}


public class Contacts
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several free Activecampaign C# libraries available. I would start by picking one... Just search GitHub.